# Jquery toggleClass effecting all

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am using this as a button all over the site. The problem is if you hover over any ".contentViewMore" then it will do it for all of them on the site. Is there a way to fix this so it only effects one button at a time or a better way of doing this?

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.contentViewMore')
  .hover(function(event) {
 $('.contentViewMoreInfo').toggleClass('contentViewMoreInfoHover');
      });
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.contentViewMore{
width: 807px;
background: #e9e9e9 url('') left;
padding-left: 33px;
float: left;
line-height: 30px;
height: 30px;
color: #565656;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .contentViewMore span{
width: 77px;
float: right;
padding: 0px 33px 0px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-khtml-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  }
  .contentViewMoreInfoHover {
background: #8eca45 url('') right;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <a class="contentViewMore" href="">
    More Posters Available.
<span class="contentViewMoreInfo">View More</span>
 </a>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtS5y/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to match the `.contentViewMoreInfo` `<span>` element inside the hovered anchor. You can either use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(".contentViewMore").hover(function(event) {
    $(this).find(".contentViewMoreInfo").toggleClass("contentViewMoreInfoHover");
});
```

Or the `context` argument to [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
$(".contentViewMore").hover(function(event) {
    $(".contentViewMoreInfo", this).toggleClass("contentViewMoreInfoHover");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentViewMore').hover(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('contentViewMoreInfoHover');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This would work but it makes the whole button green. I just wanna make the part that spans green.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS:

```
.contentViewMore:hover .contentViewMoreInfo {
    background: #8eca45;
}
```

Your code contains a lot of weird stuff, why are you positioning a background that doesn't have an image, and why are you setting `url('')` in the first place?

If you would want to do this with jQuery you would have to do this:

```
$(function(){ /* shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){ */

    $('.contentViewMore').hover(function(){

        $('.contentViewMoreInfo',this).toggleClass('contentViewMoreInfoHover');

    });

});
```

Comment: Does the css like that work in all browsers? Sorry about the background code just didn't get to putting the icon there yet was working on this part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('.contentViewMoreInfo')` inside of the hover, use `$(this)`